# If empty case in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to run a SELECT statement where `if MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED is = Null` then use the `MOPACTIVITY.MOPOTHER` field.

Would I do this as a case statement? What would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 4):

Use coalesce instead:

```
select coalesce(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED, MOPACTIVITY.MOPOTHER)
  from ...
```

You can do it with a CASE statement though:

```
select case when MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED is not null then MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED
            else MOPACTIVITY.MOPOTHER
       end
  from ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need case, [`nvl`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php) is enough (assuming your column to check is a `varchar2`):

```
select
    nvl(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED, MOPACTIVITY.MOPOTHER)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @c1 varchar(10)=NULL
select case when @c1 is null then 'asasasas' else @c1 end